# How does the algorithm of getting binary tree height work?

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree

```
int GetHeight(BinTree BT)
{
    int HL, HR, MaxH;

    if(BT)
    {
        HL = GetHeight(BT->Left);
        HR = GetHeight(BT->Right);
        MaxH = HL > HR ? HL : HR;
        return (MaxH + 1);
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I cant get the detail of this algorithm.
How does the HL and HR get their height?
Can anyone explain it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: First, there's a typo, the second `HL` assignment should be `HR`. Second, the height of a tree is by definition the height of a tree is the height of it's tallest subtrees + 1.

Comment: This is simply what recursion mean. Take a small binary tree (eg numbers from 1 to 7), use a paper sheet and a pencil, draw the tree on the paper sheet, and try to follow the algo *by hand*... It is still a wonderful way to *touch* how algos really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess the thing you're struggling with here is how recursive functions work. The important thing to note is that `GetHeight` returns an `int`.

If you examine a tree node which is non-null, the `if(BT)` condition is evaluated, and you follow the `Left` and `Right` pointers into `GetHeight` again (adding a stack frame). Now, if `Left` or `Right` is null you're going hit the `else` condition which returns `0`. Imagine a leaf node (left and right both `null`), both `HL` and `HR` will be 0, so `MaxH` will be 0, and `GetHeight` will return 1. If the call to `GetHeight` were in a recursive function call, that 1 gets passed back to the calling function, and either `HL` or `HR` is now 1, and that call will return `MaxH + 1` until you end up back at the initial call. In this way you recursively accumulate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases.

The first case is when the tree node is NULL, meaning there isn't a tree node.  That height is zero, and is captured in the "else" statement.

The second case is when the tree node is not NULL, then the hieght of the tree is the larger of the heights of the two tree branches, with 1 added.

So, if you have a single node tree, the branches both report zero, and one is added, making it a height of one.  If that single node tree has a parent node, then that branch of the parent node will report one, and the other branch might report something else (let's say zero) and the height is one plue one, or two.  And so on, until you finally get the height of the tree.